# SequelizeDatabaseError: error: null value in column "breadcrumb_id" of relation "breadcrumb_to_term_submission" violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

App crashes because Sequelize is unable to insert a row into a joint table since it deems it as a null value, even though the service has generated a value.

Service log is as follows:

```
===> [✓] > BREADCRUMBS_SERVICE > createBreadcrumb ->  successfully created a [create] breadcrumb with id: [23]
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "breadcrumb_to_term_submission" ("breadcrumb_id","submission_id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "breadcrumb_id","submission_id","created_at","updated_at","created_at","updated_at","breadcrumb_id";

  ===> [x] > BREADCRUMBS_SERVICE > createBreadcrumbToTermSubmission ->  error creating a breadcrumb with id: [23] relationship to term with id: [35] with error: [SequelizeDatabaseError: null value in column "breadcrumb_id" of relation "breadcrumb_to_term_submission" violates not-null constraint]
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
```

Error log:

```
  original: error: null value in column "breadcrumb_id" of relation "breadcrumb_to_term_submission" violates not-null constraint
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/Users/xxx/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/Users/xxx/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (/Users/xxx/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/xxx/backend/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
    length: 314,
    severity: 'ERROR',
    code: '23502',
    detail: 'Failing row contains (null, 35, 2022-11-28 17:23:55.57+00, 2022-11-28 17:23:55.57+00).',
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: 'public',
    table: 'breadcrumb_to_term_submission',
    column: 'breadcrumb_id',
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'execMain.c',
    line: '1953',
    routine: 'ExecConstraints',
    sql: 'INSERT INTO "breadcrumb_to_term_submission" ("breadcrumb_id","submission_id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "breadcrumb_id","submission_id","created_at","updated_at","created_at","updated_at","breadcrumb_id";',
    parameters: [
      null,
      35,
      '2022-11-28 17:23:55.570 +00:00',
      '2022-11-28 17:23:55.570 +00:00'
    ]
  },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO "breadcrumb_to_term_submission" ("breadcrumb_id","submission_id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "breadcrumb_id","submission_id","created_at","updated_at","created_at","updated_at","breadcrumb_id";',
  parameters: [
    null,
    35,
    '2022-11-28 17:23:55.570 +00:00',
    '2022-11-28 17:23:55.570 +00:00'
  ]
}
```

Made allowNull: false on all the models related

Sequelize query:

```
INSERT INTO "breadcrumb_to_term_submission" ("breadcrumb_id","submission_id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "breadcrumb_id","submission_id","created_at","updated_at","created_at","updated_at","breadcrumb_id";
```

**Model definitions**

> breadcrumb_to_term_submission:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const BreadcrumbToUser = sequelize.define('BreadcrumbToTermSubmission', {
        breadcrumb_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        submission_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        updated_at: DataTypes.DATE
    }, {
        // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
        // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
        // if you don't want that, set the following
        freezeTableName: true,

        // define the table's name
        tableName: 'breadcrumb_to_term_submission',
        underscored: true
    });
    BreadcrumbToUser.associate = function (models) {
        BreadcrumbToUser.belongsTo(models.TermSubmission);
        BreadcrumbToUser.belongsTo(models.Breadcrumb);
    };
    return BreadcrumbToUser;
};
```

> breadcrumb

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let Breadcrumb = sequelize.define('Breadcrumb', {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
            updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,
            before: DataTypes.TEXT,
            after: DataTypes.TEXT
        },
        {
            // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
            // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
            // if you don't want that, set the following
            freezeTableName: true,

            // define the table's name
            tableName: 'breadcrumb',
            underscored: true
        });
    Breadcrumb.associate = function (models) {
        Breadcrumb.belongsToMany(models.Term, {through: 'BreadcrumbToTerm'});
        Breadcrumb.hasMany(models.BreadcrumbToTerm);

        Breadcrumb.belongsToMany(models.TermSubmission, {through: 'BreadcrumbToTermSubmission'});
        Breadcrumb.hasMany(models.BreadcrumbToTermSubmission);

        Breadcrumb.belongsToMany(models.User, {through: 'BreadcrumbToUser'});
        Breadcrumb.hasMany(models.BreadcrumbToUser);
    };
    return Breadcrumb;
};
```

> termSubmission

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    let TermSubmission = sequelize.define('TermSubmission', {
        user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        term_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        acronym: DataTypes.STRING(60),
        definition: DataTypes.TEXT,
        links: DataTypes.JSON,
        status: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        deprecate: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        edit: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        approved_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        approved_by: DataTypes.STRING,
        rejected_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        rejected_by: DataTypes.STRING,
        created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,
        updated_by: DataTypes.STRING,
        submission_notes: DataTypes.TEXT,
        rejection_notes: DataTypes.TEXT
    }, {
        // disable the modification of tablenames; By default, sequelize will automatically
        // transform all passed model names (first parameter of define) into plural.
        // if you don't want that, set the following
        freezeTableName: true,

        // define the table's name
        tableName: 'term_submissions',
        underscored: true
    });
    TermSubmission.associate = function (models) {
        TermSubmission.belongsTo(models.User);

        TermSubmission.belongsToMany(models.Group, {through: 'TermSubmissionGroup'});
        TermSubmission.hasMany(models.TermSubmissionGroup);
        TermSubmission.belongsTo(models.Term);

        // Breadcrumbs relations
        TermSubmission.hasMany(models.BreadcrumbToTermSubmission, {foreignKey: 'submission_id'});
        TermSubmission.belongsToMany(models.Breadcrumb, {through: 'BreadcrumbToTermSubmission', foreignKey: 'submission_id'});
    };
    console.log(TermSubmission.getUser)
    return TermSubmission;
};
```

Comment: Please add the Sequelize query you executed and model definitions with associations

Comment: Just added the query, model definitions and associations. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: I don't see the Sequelize query and the data values for it